# Why should initialize list in Java

Tags: java, list

If I use the below code

```
List<String> listOfStrings=new ArrayList<>();
listOfStrings.add("first string");
```

or the following code

```
List<String> listOfStrings;
listOfStrings.add("first string");
```

to create a Java list, both the codes get compiled successfully and give same output on iterating the list. So what is the relevance of initializing the list

Comment: The second one won't compile because you've not definitely assigned a value to `listOfStrings` - assuming it's a local variable. If it's a member variable, you'd get a `NullPointerException` because you've not changed its value from the default of `null`.

Comment: you have to initialize list

Comment: As it was said, second one won't compile.

Comment: `List` is an interface, anyways (which you can't initialize as `new List<>()`). Without initialization you haven't given it an instance of anything.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 "`new ArrayList<>();`"

Comment: The compiler teels you : **The local variable listOfStrings may not have been initialized**

Comment: @AndyTurner re-read my comment.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 what am I looking for? You say "which you can't initialize as `new List<>()`"; that doesn't appear anywhere but in your comment (and now in this comment).

Comment: @AndyTurner I was emphasizing that the `List` is an interface. So his second example of wanting to add to the `List` sans initialization wouldn't even make sense given there's no provided implementation

Comment: The `List<String> listOfStrings` is a *reference* to a `List`, but not an actual list.  If you don't initialize it, it won't point to anything

Answer (score 4):

If `listOfStrings` is a local variable, the second example won't compile: you have to [*definitely assign*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) a value to a variable before you can use it.

It `listOfStrings` is a member or static variable, the second example would yield a `NullPointerException` because you're invoking the `add` method on a `null` reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are not initialising the list, you are instantiating a class or creating the new object, the list. In the second example you will receive a runtime error, because the variable listOfStrings is null.